# How to delete fingers, toes, and feet off rigify and have it work?

Tags: animation, add-on, rigify

I am trying to rig an elf in the shelf. It doesnt have feet, toes, or fingers. The rigify addon does not let me generate a rig without having these and I get some distortions when I leave them in. How can I get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fingers can be deleted from the Human metarig.

There are no toes as far as I know.

As for the feet, you cannot disable them but you could manually weight paint your character and make only the lower and upper leg affect the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Rigify works using modules. Each module is designed to represent a specific set of functions adapted for limbs (arms, fingers, torso, etc...).

You can see this in *Pose Mode* by selecting a bone at the top of a chain and looking at the *Properties Editor* > *Bone Properties Tab* > *Rigify Types Panel*:

[image: Rigify Types]

This is the thigh bone's settings. It's assigned to a `limbs.leg` type, so it needs some specific bones for it to work properly.

AFAIK the toes and feet bones cannot be removed as they are part of the required bones for the `limbs.leg` type.

What you can do is change the effect of the toes and feet deform bones after the rig is generated.

In *Pose Mode*:

1. Switch to the Deform Bones layer
2. select the toes and feet bones
3. Open the *Toggle Bone Options Menu* via <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> > Deform

[image: remove toes]

This way, when you parent your armature to your mesh, these bones will not generate any weights and will not impact the mesh.

Alternatively, you can remove them from the metarig completely, but you need to change the thigh bones' Rig Type to something else that doesn't require the toes and feet bones.

The simplest part is `basic.copy_chain`, and will just generate a simple FK setup from whatever bones you have in your chain:

[image: copy chain rig type]

Note that the result is a simple FK leg with no IK:

[image: fk leg]

For the finders, you can remove them from the metarig. Be careful though: there are "palm" bones which you need at least one to generate the hand:

[image: fingers deletion]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Didnt know that about the palm bone thanks!